# recursively list all files in directory using promises without using fs.promises api

Tags: node.js, promise

My intention is to create a script which can recursively list files in a directory. I'm using promises to solve this problem. The code I'm using is as follows.

```
var fs = require("fs")
var path = require("path")

function walk(dpath){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        fs.readdir(dpath, function(err, contents){
            if(err){
                reject(err)
            }
            else{
                Promise.all(contents.map(function(cont){
                    return new Promise(function(res, rej){
                        var fpath = path.join(dpath, cont)
                        fs.lstat(fpath, function(e, s){
                            if(e){
                                rej(e)
                            }
                            else{
                                if(s.isFile()){
                                    res(fpath)
                                }
                                else if(s.isDirectory()){
                                    walk(fpath).then(res)
                                }
                            }
                        })      
                    })
                })).then(function(resa){
                    resolve(resa.reduce((all, resa) => all.concat(resa), []));
                })
            }
        })
    })
}

walk("/home/oem/Downloads").then(console.log)
```

1. This script runs but no results are printed. but when I replace the reduce function with console.log I do get output. Please help me understand this behaviour and how can I get the result from promise.all to the callee?
2. Since usage of sync operations are frowned upon in node.js, would it be ok if I use the fs.lstatSync() for this case and what would the performance implications?

---

Thanks, have a nice day. :)

Comment: What are the reasons for not using `fs.promises` API? It would make this a very very easy script.

Comment: Additionally, how about `async/await`? It also makes this much easier.

Comment: I have no particular reason for no using fs.promises, I just want grok the concept of promises in js.

Comment: This is just a messy way to program with promises.  DO NOT mix promise control flow with plain callback control flow.  Promisify ALL your asynchronous operations and then use promises ONLY to manage the control flow.  That's why this is practically trivial with `fs.promises` and `async/await`.  You're just trying to do it the hard way where it's easy to make mistakes.  For example, you have no error handling at all on `walk(fpath.then(res)`.  That's just one of many mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really tough to tell what's going on with your code but I tried to re-write it a bit, maybe this will help:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

function walk(dirpath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(dirpath, (err, contents) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)

      Promise.all(
        contents.map(fileOrDirectory => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const statPath = path.join(dirpath, fileOrDirectory)
            fs.lstat(statPath, (err, stat) => {
              if (err) return reject(err)

              if (stat.isDirectory()) return walk(statPath).then(resolve)

              resolve([statPath])
            })
          })
        })
      )
        .then(results => {
          return results.reduce((all, x) => all.concat(...x), [])
        })
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject)
    })
  })
}

walk(path.resolve('.'))
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

One thing I noticed is that your return type is different depending on whether or not you recurse. If `stat` is a file, you should wrap it in an array so that you get the same return type as `walk(stat).then(thisIsAnArray => resolve(thisIsAnArray))`. The only other difference that I can see is I used the 'spread' operator for flattening the array.

In short, I think you have a good grasp on the actual "Promise" parts of your code, there are just a few subtleties with collecting all the results.